# Proper way to cast object to generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have an implementation of something like chain of responsibility patterns where common context has method

```
Object getVariable(String name)
```

When I get an object from the context I want to validate it with an appropriate validator. Validator interface:

```
public interface PageValidator<DTO> {

    ValidationResult validate(DTO dto);
}
```

So, when I try to do validation

```
Object dtoForValidation = getDtoForValidation(delegateExecution);
        ValidationResult validationResult = getPageValidator(delegateExecution).validate(dtoForValidation);
```

it fails with a compilation error

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?
```

So, I wanted to ask what is the proper way to design it?
(I  don't really want to let validators accept Object as input argument as it looks ugly)

Comment: There is some information missing here - you shouldn't be getting that message unless there are wildcards involved, and I don't see any in your code snippets.

Comment: But in general, if these are really your constraints (one thing gives you Object, and another thing only accepts DTO), you have no option but to cast somewhere.

Comment: This is a copy paste from mvn clean install output

Comment: Indeed, but what I'm saying is that you haven't shown us your real code.

Comment: What type does `getPageValidator(delegateExecution)` return?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, it returns PageValidator

Comment: `PageValidator` as a raw type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to change method `getValiable(String name)`. You can pass `Class<T> varClass` to this method. And your signature will be something like that:

```
<T> T getVariable(String name, Class<T> varClass);
```

If this method is placed in 3rd party library, I would recommend to you to create some wrapper for this class.

```
class Wrapper {
    private OriginalClass originalObject;

    <T> T getVariable(String name, Class<T> varClass) {
        return (T) originalObject.getVariable(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option because it's a class  from the third-party library

Comment: I edited my answer. You can make wrapper for ugly method that returns Object.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you can do one of the following.

1) Modify your `getDtoForValidation` method to return a DTO

2) Explicitly cast your object using `ValidationResult validationResult = getPageValidator(delegateExecution).validate((DTO)dtoForValidation);`

3) You mentioned you don't want your validators to accept Object as input argument, but you can do that and in the validator, start by checking Object type.